# How to write indexed collection as a static property in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to have a static property that lists indexed Store instances, but alas that does not compile, with the following error:

```
Type '({ '0750078': Store; } | { '0840021': Store; } | { '0840302': Store; })[]' is not assignable to type '{ string: Store; }[]'.
  Type '{ '0750078': Store; } | { '0840021': Store; } | { '0840302': Store; }' is not assignable to type '{ string: Store; }'.
    Type '{ '0750078': Store; }' is not assignable to type '{ string: Store; }'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''0750078'' does not exist in type '{ string: Store; }'.
```

Any idea?

```
export class Geolocation {
    lat:number;
    long: number;
    heading: number;
}

export class Store {
    nim: string;
    name: string;
    address: string;
    geolocation: Geolocation;
    constructor(
        nim: string,
        name: string, 
        address: string, 
        geolocation: Geolocation) {

        this.nim = nim;
        this.name = name; 
        this.address = address; 
        this.geolocation.lat = geolocation.lat;
        this.geolocation.long = geolocation.long;
        this.geolocation.heading = geolocation.heading;     
    }
}

export class Stores {
    store: Store;

    static stores: {string: Store}[] = [
        {'0750078': new Store('0750078', 'Kiosque de Paris',    'Place Colette 75001 Paris',                new Geolocation(48.8632,    2.3363,  90))},
        {'0840021': new Store('0840021', 'Presse tabac',        'Place de l’église 84140 Montfavet',        new Geolocation(43.9361,    4.8717, 180))},
    ];  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your static `stores` type is incorrect.
It should be `Array<{ [x: string]: Store }>`

(or `{ [x: string]: Store }[]` but I prefer the first one as it is more readable).

EDIT:
If you want an indexed store, it should be:

```
export class Stores {
  store: Store;

  static stores = {
    '0750078': new Store('0750078', 'Kiosque de Paris', 'Place Colette 75001 Paris', new Geolocation(48.8632, 2.3363, 90)),
    '0840021': new Store('0840021', 'Presse tabac', 'Place de l’église 84140 Montfavet', new Geolocation(43.9361, 4.8717, 180))
  }
}
```

You don't have to explicitly type the `stores` as the inferred type would work just fine.

Comment: I am still facing an issue Stores.stores['0840021'] returns undefined? How it comes @unional?

Comment: You have it as an array. [1] to access the second element. Do you meant to make it an indexer?  It should be an object in that case

Comment: Absolutely, my initial question was to index Stores by its NIM (its key like '0840021') @unional

Comment: Updated answer.